# Drupal 7 disable submit when pressing enter on an autocomplete field

Tags: entities, ajax

In Drupal 7, when you are within an autocomplete field on a node edit form (in my case, it is specifically an entity reference autocomplete field), pressing the Enter key submits the entire form.

How do I disable this behavior?

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/1931180

Comment: I've done some testing on simplytest.me and confirmed that this happens on a bare install, on many types of fields.  For now, I've created a module which completely disables the enter key via JS--obviously not ideal.

Comment: hey why don't you open an issue queue on drupaal.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice solution that will allow the user to press Enter in order to select an autocomplete option.

```
<script>
(function($) {

Drupal.behaviors.ACChangeEnterBehavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    $('input.form-autocomplete', context).once('ac-change-enter-behavior', function() {
      $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        var ac = $('#autocomplete');
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && typeof ac[0] != 'undefined') {
          e.preventDefault();
          var fauxEvent = $.Event('mousedown'); // Create an event to trigger
          $('li.selected', ac).trigger(fauxEvent);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Note: This will only override the behavior of Enter while the autocomplete dropdown is visible. Otherwise, pressing Enter does the normal behavior (submits the form).

But if you want to halt form submission via Enter in any input field, try the following:

```
<script>
(function($) {

Drupal.behaviors.DisableInputEnter = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    $('input', context).once('disable-input-enter', function() {
      $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for both examples, they did help me! Only one comment: a closing } is missing right before the last line of code: )(jQuery);

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more concise version of answer #2 (the faux event is not needed).

```
<script>
!(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.ACChangeEnterBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Prevent the autocomplete from triggering the submit event.
      $('input.form-autocomplete', context).once('ac-change-enter-behavior').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && this !== undefined) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

    }
  };
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter in many fields would trigger the form submit.
The only way you can disable this behavior is by custom JS, as you've done.